# Extracting data from simplexml_load_file not working

Tags: php, xml, extract

I'm stuck on getting a value from a xml file, I've decided to use simplexml as it makes life easier but atm its doing the opposite.

My xml file look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fslb server="12345">
<statistics>
    <frontend-connections>145</frontend-connections>
    <global-response-time-average>1899ms</global-response-time-average>
    <ecm-blacklist-size>0</ecm-blacklist-size>
    <backend-connections>0 of 0</backend-connections>
    <global-max-response-time>6888ms</global-max-response-time>     
    <global-ecm-cache-size>2396</global-ecm-cache-size>
    <global-queue-length>0</global-queue-length>
    <global-sidless-poll-average>0.00</global-sidless-poll-average>
    <actual-card-requests>0</actual-card-requests>
    <sid-sidless-requests>75% [109]/24% [36]</sid-sidless-requests>
    <invalidated-clients>0</invalidated-clients>
    <global-queue-average>0.00</global-queue-average>
    <global-max-sidless-polls>0</global-max-sidless-polls>
    <average-requests-per-card>0.00</average-requests-per-card>
    <global-cache-efficiency>0%</global-cache-efficiency>
    <total-requests-received>102934</total-requests-received>
</statistics>
<active-users>
    <user name="RS.DOS" unread-messages="0" ipaddress="xxxx" client="Mgcamd" loggedonsince="2014-08-18 06:01:03p" requests="338" period=" 8.53" sid="0695" service-name="INT" request-handling="Queued in GC (External)" hop-list="[0]: None" hash="DE:26" latency="1900" />
    <user name="S9" unread-messages="0" ipaddress="xxxx" client="Mgcamd" loggedonsince="2014-08-18 06:01:03p" requests="263" period="10.97" sid="0174" service-name=" XD" request-handling="Queued in GC (External)" hop-list="[0]: None" hash="80:C0" latency="748" />
    <user name="M1" unread-messages="0" ipaddress="174.93.86.83" client="Newcamd" loggedonsince="2014-08-18 06:01:03p" requests="12844" period=" 0.22" sid="0688" service-name="INT" request-handling="Global Cached CWs" hop-list="[0]: None" hash="4A:3F" latency="0" />
    <user name="S9" unread-messages="0" ipaddress="xxxx" client="Mgcamd" loggedonsince="2014-08-18 06:01:03p" requests="300" period=" 9.61" sid="0650" service-name="INT" request-handling="Queued in GC (External)" hop-list="[0]: None" hash="8A:4C" latency="909" />
</active-users>
```

`</fslb>`

My end goal is to extract the data from one "user" line (or the statistics line) and output it to mysql so that its saved in my db.  The outputting part seems pretty easy, however I can't even get the data to be extracted in the first place -.-.  This is my php code:

```
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "10000M");
$file_xml = "users.xml";
if(!file_exists($file_xml))
{
    exit('Failed to open');
}

$fslb = simplexml_load_file($file_xml, 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json_string = json_encode($fslb);  
$result_array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
//print_r($fslb);
echo('<p> Total number of connections: ');
echo $result_array->statistics[0]->{'frontend-connections'};
echo('</p>');
echo('<p> Global-response-time-average: ');
echo $result_array->statistics[0]->{'global-response-time-average'};
echo('</p>');
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out how I can extract some data but it just wont go!

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [server] => 12345 ) [statistics] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [frontend-connections] => 145 [global-response-time-average] => 1899ms [ecm-blacklist-size] => 0 [backend-connections] => 0 of 0 [global-max-response-time] => 6888ms [global-ecm-cache-size] => 2396 [global-queue-length] => 0 [global-sidless-poll-average] => 0.00 [actual-card-requests] => 0 [sid-sidless-requests] => 75% [109]/24% [36] [invalidated-clients] => 0 [global-queue-average] => 0.00 [global-max-sidless-polls] => 0 [average-requests-per-card] => 0.00 [global-cache-efficiency] => 0% [total-requests-received] => 102934 ) [active-users] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [user] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => RS.DOS [unread-messages] => 0 [ipaddress] => xxxx [client] => Mgcamd [loggedonsince] => 2014-08-18 06:01:03p [requests] => 338 [period] => 8.53 [sid] => 0695 [service-name] => INT [request-handling] => Queued in GC (External) [hop-list] => [0]: None [hash] => DE:26 [latency] => 1900 ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => S9 [unread-messages] => 0 [ipaddress] => xxxx [client] => Mgcamd [loggedonsince] => 2014-08-18 06:01:03p [requests] => 263 [period] => 10.97 [sid] => 0174 [service-name] => XD [request-handling] => Queued in GC (External) [hop-list] => [0]: None [hash] => 80:C0 [latency] => 748 ) ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => M1 [unread-messages] => 0 [ipaddress] => 174.93.86.83 [client] => Newcamd [loggedonsince] => 2014-08-18 06:01:03p [requests] => 12844 [period] => 0.22 [sid] => 0688 [service-name] => INT [request-handling] => Global Cached CWs [hop-list] => [0]: None [hash] => 4A:3F [latency] => 0 ) ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [name] => S9 [unread-messages] => 0 [ipaddress] => xxxx [client] => Mgcamd [loggedonsince] => 2014-08-18 06:01:03p [requests] => 300 [period] => 9.61 [sid] => 0650 [service-name] => INT [request-handling] => Queued in GC (External) [hop-list] => [0]: None [hash] => 8A:4C [latency] => 909 ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: This `service-name=" XD"` contains a space. Whether it makes a difference or not `service-name="XD"` - and `period=" 8.53"`

Comment: Yea i saw that but even with or without the space my code isnt working D:

Comment: Why aren't you looking at the `print_r` output? You converted into an all-array structure. Thus your `$result_array->statistics` would throw a notice. Enable error_reporting.

Comment: in my php.ini: error_reporting = E_ALL  it is enabled o.o
edit:i've edited my post with the simplexml post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works for me

var_dump((string)$fslb->statistics->{"frontend-connections"});

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php

Comment: Thanks at least im getting somewhere, but just a question i get string(3) "145" as a response.  How do I just get 145?

Comment: string(3) - is an output of var_dump. You'll get 145 if you write down $a = (string)$fslb->statistics->{"frontend-connections"};

Comment: AFAIK SimpleXMLElement doesn't have any method returns value of the node. So the only way to get it is to cast it to string (or another type you need).

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!  I did what you said about $a = ... and it worked!!  Thanks alot!!!!

Comment: sorry if i may ask one last question:  I did var_dump((string) $fslb->{'active-users'}->user[0]['name']);  and in return I got string(6) "RS.DOS"  which is what I wanted.  However what if I want to search for a name lets say "S9" is the name I want to search for and I want to extract the entire row from that name, how would you go about doing that?  because this xml file is dynamic, it changes every second and the user that I want to search for will not always be in the first array.

Comment: In this case I'll use xpath for searching. Something like:
    $result = $fslb->xpath('//active-users/user[@name="S9"]');
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        var_dump((string)$row->attributes()["name"]);
        var_dump((string)$row->attributes()["name"]);
    }

Comment: NVM!  THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!  You've saved me hours of searching D: